# How i add radio button in table layout in android

Tags: favorites

I have a Table Layout and have some rows. In each row I have one radio button. My question is that.

1. How can i make only one radio button is checked at a time others will have to be unchecked.Only one at time.
2. Whenever I will check any radio button then in bottom there will be a button bar of 4 buttons will appear.I have made a button bar which will remain in bottom but i want that it will appear only when I will click on any radio button.

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#C85A17">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 

        <ScrollView 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"> 

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#C85A17">

    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="Cocktail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="Bol Bachchan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:text="Rowdy Rathor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:text="Shanghai"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:text="Jannat 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text6"
            android:text="Maximum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/top7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:src="@drawable/music"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            android:cropToPadding="true" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text7"
            android:text="Teri Meri Kahani"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" /> 

</TableLayout>    
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right">
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>         
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
     android:gravity="center"
     >
<Button android:id="@+id/share" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Share" />

<Button android:id="@+id/activate" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Activate" />
<Button android:id="@+id/listen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Listen" />

<Button android:id="@+id/deactivate" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Deactivate" />
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me out guys.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am still waiting for the answer.......